# Inconsistent behaviour of box-shadow with transition

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-transitions, box-shadow

I have a button which will get a `box-shadow` on `hover`. It also has a `transition`. My problem is, it doesn't always display the same result, sometimes the `box-shadow` will be offset by a few px and not be equal on all sides as shown on the image:

[image]

Below is my code and here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e09wstrp/) demo.

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:25px;
  transition:.2s;
  background:lightgrey;
  border-radius:25px;
}

div:hover{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

As you can see if you remove the `transition` the `box-shadow` is deisplayed properly.

```css
div{
  width:100px;
  height:25px;
  background:lightgrey;
  border-radius:25px;
}

div:hover{
  box-shadow:0px 0px 10px green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

What is even more interesting to me is that JSFiddle demo, would display different outputs after deleting and pasting back some code while keeping it without changes overally, or by running the same code again, or reducing the transition time. It's hard for me to explain how to reproduce this but you might see it yourself if you play with a bit. 
My question is how to keep it consistent, and most importantly how to keep the `box-shadow` equal while keeping the transition.

@edit

[Video of issue](https://streamable.com/shfl7)

Also I've made a video of how I see the differences since some people reported not to see any problem. Is it at all possible it's somehow fault of my screen? (Hopefully the issue is visible on the video or maybe I'm just going crazy)

@edit2

It seems like it is a browser issue. Originally I encountered the issue on latest Chrome version, couldn't reporoduce the problem on latest Firefox. After discovering that thanks to comments I've added webkit prefixes to `transition` and `box-shadow` but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error with no success. To me everything works pretty fine, even after deleting / pasting the code, or modifying values. Check out with another browser (I'm running on Chrome). What I would suggest however would be to add "border: 1px solid lightgrey;" to your div. On top of that, you should consider the <button></button> tag instead of a <div></div> tag, it's good practice.

Comment: ^ Same for me on Safari

Comment: @florian i see, do you see a difference in the output of the two code snippets?

Comment: @aMJay I've run the two code snippets, and there isn't any single difference (except with the animation). To double check, I've zoomed tenfold, same result :)

Comment: @florian I've added a video recording of how I see the issue, hopefully you can see what I mean through that, if not, maybe I'm just going crazy

Comment: very strange, maybe it's browser related... can you try with something different than jsfiddle? I'd recommend to run the code on your local, see if there's any difference

Comment: @florian actually it seems like you are right about it being browser issue, I cannot reproduce the issue on firefox, for the record originally I encountered it on Chrome. Afterwards I added webkit prefixes but it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it seems to be a bug but to overcome this you can do it differently using a pseudo element where you apply the box-shadow but you animate another property (scale, opacity, width/height, etc)

```css
div.box{
  width:100px;
  height:25px;
  margin:10px;
  background:lightgrey;
  border-radius:25px;
  position:relative;
}
div.box::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  box-shadow:0 0 10px green;
  border-radius:inherit;
  transition:.2s;
  transform:scale(0.8);
}

div.box:hover::before{
  transform:scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```